# How to create manifest for MS office 2007 add-in?

Tags: c#, installation, vsto, add-in

Hello 
I have the Addin for Word 2007 that is creted using VSTO. 
I would like create installer for add in and found short manual for registry entries (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx).
According to manual we should create Manifest node in the registry and specify path to manifest file:

*Required. The full path of the deployment manifest for the add-in. The path can be a location on the local computer, a network share (UNC), or a Web server (HTTP).*

What is manifest file? Could you please describe me how to create manifest file mo ms office addin?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manifest files should be generated automatically by Visual Studio in the output folder:

- the file with **.vsto** extension is the deployment manifest
- the file with **.dll.manifest** extension is the application manifest

Edit: I found a tutorial which may help you with the deployment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2010/11/01/deploying-a-vsto-word-2007-add-in-to-all-users-visual-studio-2008-sp1.aspx

Comment: I cannot find the specified files in project output folder after rebuilding project... May be some additional configurations is needed? Visual Studio 2008 is used for build.

Comment: They are generated by default. Perhaps you are looking in the wrong folder. I edited my answer and added a link to a tutorial which may help you.